# For any power of $a$, it is always possible to find another power such that they both have the same remainder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $a$ and $p$ are integers, then for any $n \in \Bbb{N}$, it is always
> possible to find $m$ such that
>
> $$a^n\equiv a^m\pmod p$$

This might be a pretty basic question but I can't seem to find a proof since it seems self-evident. I was wondering if this is some sort of axiom or if it's a property that needs to be proved. It is quite different from a result that stablishes that for any number $a$, there is always possible to find 2 powers such that $a^n\equiv a^m\pmod p$, for any $p$.

In this case, let's say we have any $a^n$ which leaves some remainder $r$ when divided by $p$. Is it possible to find another power of $a$ that has the same remainder when divided by $p$? How to justifiy this?

Comment: If $p$ is prime, for every number $a$ there exists a power $b$ such that $a^b \mod p = 1$, so you can just set $m = n + b$. In fact, if $p$ doesn’t divide $a$, then choosing $b = p -1$ satisfies this property, by Fermat’s Little Theorem.

Comment: However if $p=4$ and $a=2$ for example, the remainder $2^1$ is unique. So $p$ being prime is important.

Comment: @paulinho I would appreciate a source where to find a proof of your first statement.

Comment: @NotAMathematician - See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem